# count aggregation base on key value and make keys become values in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Explanation: I have several documents,  I want to count base on `typ` and want to make a list of `name` and `date_key`. In the end we have **one document**, that count the `typ`. please see the expected output.
**Remarks**

1. `typ` value is a variable.it will just count the occurrence of variable value.
2. `data` key contain one element, for example just date. but we need the keys as value, keys can be multiple, at the moment there are 2 keys, it can me 3 or more. see the expected output keys are showing as a list `["el1", "el2]`

```
[
  {
    "typ": "ABC",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "XYZ",
        "in_data": {
          "date": {
            "el2": "2015-01-10",
            "el1": "2014-01-10"
          },
          "version" : "0.22",
          "model" : "2015"

        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "typ": "ABC",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "LMNO",
        "in_data": {
          "date": {
            "el2": "2015-01-10",
            "el1": "2014-01-10"
          },
          "version" : "0.22",
          "model" : "2014"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
{
    "typ": "EDC",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "QWERTY",
        "in_data": {
          "date": {
            "el3": "2015-01-10",
            "el4": "2014-01-10"
          },
          "version" : "0.52",
          "model" : "2010"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected OutPut

```
[
{
    "typ_count" : 2,
    "name" : ["XYZ", "LLMNO"],
    "date_key" : ["el1", "el2"]

},
{
    "typ_count" : 1,
    "name" : ["QWERTY"],
    "date_key" : ["el3", "el4"]

},
]
```

Comment: Does `typ` always have a constant value of "ABC" or it's a variable? If it's variable then what's the expected output for the different values? Also, does the `data` key only contain one element or can be many? If so, can you update your question to include sample data for all these scenarios and their corresponding expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I update the question, did you understand know. if you still have question most welcome

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I kind of understood but still not clear about the `data` array field in the root document, you seem to have thought that I meant the `in_data` document which only has one key i.e. `date`. What I really meant was the `data` list, does it ONLY have one element i.e. the `in_data` document or there can be multiple `{ in_data: { ... } }` embedded documents? Hope the question is clear

Comment: please see the input document  `in_data` contain the multiple element but we just needed `date_key` (see the output for `date_key` )

Comment: Ok, I guess my question is mainly on the data design, can the `data` array have multiple elements (objects/documents) e.g. can it be like `{ "data": [ { "name": "DEF", "in_data": <document> },  { "name": "GHI", "in_data": <document> }, ...] }` or it ONLY has one document/element i.e. `{ "data": [ { "name": "DEF", "in_data": <document> } ] }`?

Comment: `data` array have one element, like you explain in last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the `data` field is an array that contains only ONE element, you just need to flatten it either by using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/) or [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operators but would recommend any of the last two operators for an optimal aggregation pipeline operation.

Your aggregation pipeline should have essentially 4 stages: the initial stage is to transform ([`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) pipeline) the `data` key into an embedded document since its design as an array is redundant as it **ONLY** has one element, better flatten it so that it becomes an embedded document.

The next pipeline should be another transformation operation where you use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to create a list of the `date` keys.

From there you need to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) the documents to aggregate the `typ_count` using [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) and create another list of the `date` keys along with the `name` list using [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/).

The final pipeline uses [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) and [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatarrays/) with a [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to filter out duplicates in the date_key list produced above.

Your overall pipeline should be as follows

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $addFields: {
        data: { $arrayElemAt: ['$data', 0] } // OR data: { $first: '$data' }
    } },
    { $addFields: {
        name: '$data.name',
        date_key: {
            $map: {
                input: { $objectToArray: '$data.in_data.date' },
                in: '$$this.k'
            }
        }
    } },
    { $group: {
        _id: '$typ',
        typ_count: { $sum: 1 },
        name: { $push: '$name' },
        date_key: { $push: '$date_key' }
    } },
    { $project: {
       _id: 0,
        typ_count: 1,
        name: 1,
        date_key: {
            $reduce: {
                input: '$date_key',
                initialValue: [],
                in: { 
                    $concatArrays: [ 
                        '$$value', 
                        {
                            $cond: [
                                { $in: ["$$this", ["$$value"]] },
                                [], 
                                "$$this"
                            ]
                        } 
                    ]  
                }                
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9HWI-ivm-K0)